# How to catch the end of an application?

Tags: android

I have an application, where I have put a connection to e certain service in a custom Application class, so that all activities can access it, but I need to close the service once my application is closed.

I want to send the bundled data just one time, not every time a single activity hits onPause/Destroy().

I also figured onTerminate() in the Application class is not always invoked.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `onTerminate` "is for use in emulated process environments." it should actually never be called on a real device app because the app process is just killed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are targeting API level 14 or above you can use the registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks to register a listener and count the launches/stops in onActivityResumed and onActivityStopped. When the counter is 0 then you know there is no more activity in the stack and you can close your service

Comment: Thanks Aleks! This approach seams to be doing exactly what I needed :)
Here is a very helpful article for future wanderers - http://www.mjbshaw.com/2012/12/determining-if-your-android-application.html
I can now react properly to the application going in the background and coming back to front.

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately, there is no callback / method to detect when your application process has stopped, or going to be stopped.  @Alex suggestion to listen to the Activity lifecycle callbacks can be more tricky then it seems.

but if you want to detect this only for purposes of stopping running `Service` , then this problem is not relevant, because **if your process stooped, then all running services it owns is also stopped anyway!!**

if you meant that you want to stop the service when the application is **not in foreground** (completely different thing..) then the solutions is different:

if you'll always use `bindService()` instead of `startService()` within the `onResume` activity callback, and in the `onPause()` stop it,  then when your app would enter background - the service will be stopped automatically.

another option would be to use the Service callbacks to detect if currently there is bounded activity:

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    mBoundedToActivity = true;
    return mBinder;
}

@Override
public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
    mBoundedToActivity = true;
    super.onRebind(intent);
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    mBoundedToActivity = false;
    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}
```

Comment: I don't really care how the service dies, I have data that is collected from all the activities and bundled in one place, I just need to send this data to the server via the service once the user leaves my application(he's done using it and backs out of it or opens another, while mine stays in the background and eventually dies anytime soon). I just want to catch the moment my app dies for good and use the service to push the collected data right before that. This ensures me one single connection, instead of listening to the onPause() of every single activity in the app.

Comment: @troty_master: "app dies for good" = app process stoped?  or = app in background?   I still not understand what of the two you mean

Comment: I guess both would work, as long as I don't miss the chance to send the data and I don't send it multiple times for a single use of my application.

Comment: @troty_master: as I wrote in my answer - there is no way to detect when the process been killed, so it leaves only the foreground detection.   to do that you can follow this turorial  -http://getpocket.com/a/read/455668102

Comment: Thanks Tal, appreciate your time, I shall do that :)